# memory allocation of object attributes in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management

```
class A {
  public:
    int i;
};

int main() {
  A *obj = new A();
  return 0;
}
```

In the following code, when the object for A is created it is created in heap, but where is the memory of i in the obj created ??
Is it created on heap or stack or is there a different behavior??

Comment: That syntax is invalid in C++. It won't even compile.

Comment: I think you mean `A *obj = new A();`.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>As-is, your code won't compile -- `new` returns a pointer, and you're trying to assign that to an object instead of a pointer (perhaps more accustomed to Java?)</strike>

Assuming you fix that:

```
A *obj = new A();
```

The entire object that `obj` points at is allocated on the heap. That includes the storage for `i`. `obj` itself is a pointer, which is allocated with `auto` storage (i.e., normally on the stack).

As an aside, it's fairly unusual that you want to do this anyway. Most of the time, you just define an object (e.g., `A obj;`) and if there's any heap allocation involved, the object will manage it (including cleaning up the storage when the object goes out of scope).